# PHP Encoding Conversion to Windows-1252 whilst keeping UTF-8 Compatibility

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

I need to convert uploaded filenames with an unknown encoding to Windows-1252 whilst also keeping UTF-8 compatibility.

As I pass on those files to a controller (on which I don't have any influence), the files have to be Windows-1252 encoded. This controller then again generates a list of valid file(names) that are stored via MySQL into a database - therefore I need UTF-8 compatibility. Filenames passed to the controller and filenames written to the database MUST match. So far so good.

In some rare cases, when converting to "Windows-1252" (like with te character "ï"), the character is converted to something invalid in UTF-8. MySQL then drops those invalid characters - as a result filenames on disk and filenames stored to the database don't match anymore. This conversion, which failes sometimes, is achieved with simple recoding:

```
$sEncoding       = mb_detect_encoding($sOriginalFilename);
$sTargetFilename = iconv($sEncoding, "Windows-1252//IGNORE", $sOriginalFilename);
```

To prevent invalid characters being generated by the conversion, I then again can remove all invalid UTF-8 characters from the recoded string:

```
ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");
$sEncoding       = mb_detect_encoding($sOriginalFilename);
$sTargetFilename = iconv($sEncoding, "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT", $sOriginalFilename);
$sTargetFilename = mb_convert_encoding($sTargetFilename, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
```

But this will completely remove / recode any special characters left in the string. For example I lose all "äöüÄÖÜ" etc., which are quite regular in german language.

If you know a cleaner and simpler way of encoding to Windows-1252 (without losing valid special characters), please let me know.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is that [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) does not do exactly what you think it does. It attempts to detect the character encoding but it does it from a fairly limited list of predefined encodings. By default, those encodings are the ones returned by [mb_detect_order()](http://php.net/mb_detect_order). In my computer they are:

- ASCII
- UTF-8

So this function is completely useless unless you take care of compiling a list of candidate encodings and feeding the function with it.

Additionally, there's basically no reliable way to guess the encoding of an arbitrary input string, even if you restrict yourself to a small subset of encodings. In your case, `Windows-1252` is so close to `ISO-8859-1` and `ISO-8859-15` that you have no way to tell them apart other than visual inspection of key characters like ¤ or €.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a string be Windows-1252 and UTF-8 at the same time. The character sets are identical for the first 128 characters (they contain e.g. the basic latin alphabet), but when it goes beyond that (like for Umlauts), it's either one or the other. They have different code points in UTF-8 than they have in Windows-1252.

Answer (score 1):

Keep to ASCII in the filesystem - if you need to sustain characters outside ASCII in a filename, there are
schemes you can use to represent unicode characters while keeping to ASCII.

For example, percent encoding:

`äöüÄÖÜ.txt` <-> `%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C.txt`

Of course this will hit the file name limit pretty fast and is not very optimal.

How about [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)?

`äöüÄÖÜ.txt` <-> `xn--4caa7cb2ac.txt`